# Присвоение переменной значение ячейки

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

### Требуется в переменную занести значение SELECT'a:

```
(SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT PERSON_EMAIL FROM PERSONS  WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND ID ORDER BY rownum DESC)  WHERE  rownum=1);
```

#### Пробую делать так:

```
EMAIL := (SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT PERSON_EMAIL FROM PERSONS  WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND ID ORDER BY rownum DESC)  WHERE  rownum=1);
```

#### или так:

```
SET EMAIL = SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT PERSON_EMAIL FROM PERSONS  WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND ID ORDER BY rownum DESC)  WHERE  rownum=1;
```

**При этом предварительно объявив email в DECLARE таким образом:**

```
email varchar2(4000);
```

Но в любом случае не даёт выполнить команду. Как правильно занести в переменную?

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ на свой предыдущий вопрос, там как раз выборка из запроса попадает в переменную (используется предложение INTO)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте предложение INTO:

```
SELECT PERSON_EMAIL
  INTO email
  FROM (
        SELECT PERSON_EMAIL FROM PERSONS
         WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND ID ORDER BY rownum DESC
       )
 WHERE  rownum=1
```

P.S. Вообще запрос немного странный, вы пытаетесь получить некую "последнюю" запись. Но Oracle как и другие СУБД не гарантирует порядка выбора записей без указания точного порядка сортировки. Т.е. "последней" (с максимальным rownum) теоретически может оказаться какая угодно запись.

Answer (score 2):

1) Присвоение переменной из запроса делается следующим синтаксисом.

```
declare 
  email varchar(4000);
begin
    select
       email
    into
       email
    from 
       имя таблицы
    where 
       ....
end;
```

2) В такой запрос должно возвращаться ровно одно значение, не больше не меньше, иначе оракл выдаст необработанное исключение. Если у вас может возвращаться пустое значение можно либо обрабатывать это исключение или возвращать максимальное значение через функцию max.

3) Если вам нужно вывести список всех адресов через запятую, можно в выборке использовать запросе функцию LISTAGG:

```
   select
       LISTAGG (email,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY email)
    into
        email
    from 
         имя таблицы
    where 
       id between 10 and 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `SELECT INTO`, пример:

```
declare sysd date;
begin
  select sysdate into sysd from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(sysd);
end;
```

[Мануал](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm)